# Cant open Page on github

Tags: html, github

I am new to GitHub and trying to complete assignment which requires files under subfolder. Unfortunately I couldn`t run the index.html file from sub folder. When I try to open pages from /setting/pages...it opens just readme file and nothing else. but works from directly from repository.

i tryed almost every possible way to open but I think I need more help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you're trying to `deploy` your assignment going to `githubPages` (in settings/ pages).

if you want to run the website in your local repository you can use `live server`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not too clear, but try

- typing cd *subfolder name* in your terminal, and then try running the code in your subdirectory.